# Why are search engines (Google, Bing) returning ROS wiki mirror search results instead of results for the main site?

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've noticed that when I google something, e.g. "[roslaunch machine tag](https://www.google.com/search?q=roslaunch+machine+tag)", that the results that typically show up for the wiki pages are from the UMD mirror of the wiki rather than the wiki itself. I'm not sure when this started happening but it definitely didn't happen before, as this has always been my (admittedly somewhat lazy) way to access the documentation.

Did something change on the server side of the (real) wiki that is making Google avoid it in search results? It might not just be Google, either--I'm having trouble getting Bing to return any ros.org wiki results either..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36533/why-are-search-engines-(google,-bing)-returning-ros-wiki-mirror-search-results-instead-of-results-for-the-main-site?/) by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2264 on 2012-06-14

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-14**:
Seems like it's been doing that for a long time.

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2012-06-14**:
Yeah, it might not be a recent thing, just I've been doing a bit more ROS related Googling lately. Either way, still annoying. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps the maintainers can add a [canonical link element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) to the wiki pages to point at ROS.org.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-06-16**:
Ticketed https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3989